# PHP: how to get variables/classes from external file

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm new in PHP and my question is REALLY basic today.

I wrote the simple script, which scans `projects` folder and dynamically creates list of thumbnails and includes short description of every project. Very simple:

```
<ul class="projects">
    <?php
    $dir = '../../projects/';
    $names = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        if ($name === '.' or $name === '..')
            continue;
        echo '<li class="project"><a href="' . $dir . $name . '">' 
             . '<img src="' . $dir . $name . '/project/image.jpg" />'
             . '<div class="desc">';
        include ($dir . $name . '/project/desc.php');
        echo '</div></a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

That works great, but I want to have some of them marked as `featured` or `new`.

What is the simplest way to add some css classes or variables to each project from external file? I guess I have to create `*.php` file but how do I access particular information stored in it?

Comment: Check out [include](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [require](http://ca.php.net/require).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all the information packaged: in an array, in a class instance, whatever suits you..

```
$info = array(
  'name' => 'Test project',
  'desc' => 'This is a....',
  'new'  => true,
  ...
);
```

Comment: That's it! Super simple answer. Thank You!